# Django development console custom/debug messages

Tags: django, debugging, console

Is there a way to print messages to Django development console?

I'm running 1.1 Django in buildout environment.

So running `bin/django runserver` (`manage.py runserver`) it shows development console where it writes resources, actions taken (equivalent of apache access/error logs(?)).

I want to print custom messages to that console for debugging purposes that it wouldn't kill the action just notice me.

Should i use `logging` module or is there other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure you just want it in development, you can simply use `print` - the message appears in the console.

However, you will need to delete the print statement before you deploy to production, as this will cause an error with Apache.

A better long-term solution is to use the `logging` module, configured to output to the console.

Comment: So with logging i could post custom log messages. But where it would be stored? access or error logs? I assume access. am i wrong?

Comment: You should read up on logging @JackLeo as setting up logging can be less than trivial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/

Comment: @nicorellius well this was asked 4 years ago. As of right now I would use ether depending on requirements. runserver - logging only, but for custom manage commands print might be an option.

Comment: @JackLeo I realize this post was made long ago. But if you end up here and you develop web applications with Django, you owe it to yourself to study logging. It's often misunderstood and misconfigured.